# Installing third party javascript

Tags: javascript, intercom

I'm installing Intercom (https://www.intercom.com) for customer engagement on my site. With the recommended installation the javascript snippet they gave would have my intercom app_id exposed in the page source.

May not be a big deal, but I was wondering if there was a better way where I could keep that hidden.

Comment: Generally it's on the provider of the service to provide you a way to whitelist domains, which is how google maps/charts/etc. work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May not be a big deal

It isn't.

> but I was wondering if there was a better way where I could keep that hidden

You can't.

Intercom need the browser to tell them your ID for their approach to work.

This means you must tell the browser your ID.

The browser is the property of the user and it answers to them.

It is not possible to give the browser information and keep it secret from the user who owns the browser.